# What criteria are used to accept/reject hypotheses in ridge regression?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, inference, ridge-regression

On what basis might one accept/reject a hypothesis when running ridge regression?

For example, if I have five predictor variables as part of a ridge regression, what criterion would I use to accept or reject the hypothesis that each of these predictors are linked to the outcome variable?

I know that bootstrapping can be used to produce standard errors in ridge regression but there are some convincing arguments against using them to calculate p-values or really reporting them at all (e.g. Goeman, Meijer & Chaturvedi, 2012). As such, what else could I use?

I've been running ridge regression in SPSS so the output is fairly restricted to a ridge trace (k and coefficients) and a plot of k and r-squared. Would anything in those suffice?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is discussed in Cule et al. BMC Bioinformatics 2011 http://www.biomedcentral.com/content/pdf/1471-2105-12-372.pdf
and the associated R package : http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ridge/ridge.pdf